# Handling a model's save method using an atomic transaction in Django

Tags: django

The question is honestly pretty self-explanatory. I have 2 models which are related. It goes like this:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction

class Item(models.Model):
    total_score = models.IntegerField()

    def set_score(self):
         ...

class Review(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                super(Review, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                self.item.set_score()
        except IntegrityError:
            handle_exception()
```

Basically, whenever a review is saved, its item's score is updated using the `set_score()` method. I put the whole thing in an atomic transaction because obviously, I don't want a review to update and the item's score to remain un-updated. Thats like a breeding ground for potential bugs. Anyway, is the right way to do it? I feel like I have no way of testing this in my local server as it is impossible to create an error which saves the review but not update the score. Thanks.

Note: I know there are better ways to handle the score of an item based on its reviews. That is not the point of the question. It is a made up scenario for the sake of explaining what I want to do. So, please, no answers mentioning that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do it as you have mentioned but it is better to use **business logic/ transaction logic** outside of save() method. This would provide you better integrity and also abstraction.

Writing this logic inside save function is shorthand to do (*pretty easy*).

*other way to do this*

**utils.py**

```
def update_score(*args, **kwargs):
    with transaction.atomic():
        review = Review(*args, **kwargs)
        review.item.set_score()
        review.save()
```

If this wouldn't helpful for you than writing that transaction block inside save() method or simply pick your code into other method and wrap that with exception but handle that try-catch block with proper exception because it makes side effects / Buggy code. Rest of the things would be fine and work.

> Just remember that do not handle exceptions inside the transaction atomic block.

Comment: How would you do this outside of a save method? Post-save signals would not work, because you can't make those atomic.

Comment: I mean by writing separately inside `utils.py`.

Comment: But how would you structure that? You would still have to over-ride the save method it seems, unless I'm missing something. Would really appreciate some code examples in your answer.

Comment: I 've updated my answer. Please have a look into it. If you stuck at somewhere than please attach exception message or your expected behaviour of code.